# What level of intimacy is generally acceptable for unmarried couples from the standpoint of the Bible?

Tags: bible, sexuality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sex outside of marriage is a sin. But what about "less than sex"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/109/sex-outside-of-marriage-is-a-sin-but-what-about-less-than-sex)

Pre-marital sex is generally considered part of sexual immorality, <sup>[1]</sup> as such we should abstain from it as we do other sexually-immoral acts. <sup>[2]</sup>

But what does the Bible say about other levels of physical intimacy between unmarried partners?

---

<sup>[1] 1 Corinthians 7:2</sup>

<sup>[2] Acts 15:20, 1 Corinthians 5:1; 1 Corinthians 6:13, 1 Corinthians 18; 1 Corinthians 10:8; 2 Corinthians 12:21; Galatians 5:19; Ephesians 5:3; Colossians 3:5; 1 Thessalonians 4:3; Jude 7</sup>

Comment: The accepted answer to the duplicate question exactly sums up my take on it. Sexual activity does not follow a straight (no pun intended) line of progression, and as such there's not a single division in it that separates what's sinful from what isn't.