# Is the "belly of a whore" phrase from the Bible?

Tags: biblical-basis, sexuality, protestant-bible

Several times, I have heard a phrase along the lines of "It is better to plant thy seed in the belly of a whore than to be cast upon the ground."

Is there a biblical reference for this phrase? I can't find it in the protestant Bible...

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, @Russel Thackston!

Comment: [It's an urban legend (link)](http://www.blueletterbible.org/faq/sayings.cfm#belly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such verse in the Bible. The reference to spilling one's seed on the ground comes from [Genesis 38:9 NASB](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2038:9&version=NASB):

> Onan knew that the offspring would not be his; so when he went in to
>   his brother's wife, he wasted his seed on the ground in order not give
>   offspring to his brother.

From [here](http://www.probe.org/site/c.fdKEIMNsEoG/b.4222913/k.7BE/Is_There_A_Verse_About_Casting_Ones_Seed_in_the_Belly_of_a_Whore.htm).

There's a fuller explanation from the site I linked to as well.

This is usually a saying that comes up in reference to masturbation.  That's not really what the verse is talking about, but that subject has been discussed on this site [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-masturbation-a-sin).