# Why is masturbation a sin? (without human arguments, Pentecostalism)

Tags: sin, pentecostalism, masturbation

My side: I believe in the gifts of the Holy Spirit , in Bible (solo), that it's possible to have deep experiences nowadays with God as Ezekiel, Jeremiah and Paul did by fasting and seeking souls, and if you to die in sin you'll lose your salvation, they usually call this in my country as Pentecostalism.

This [post](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/48/what-is-the-biblical-basis-to-claim-that-masturbation-is-a-sin) (**What is the biblical basis to claim that masturbation is a sin?**) doesn't have answers that answers me, their answers are either about adultery in heart, that masturbation is not sin by itself but the impure thinking is, onan based (which is a very poor argument) and rational arguments (see below).

First of all, I'm not wondering with myself if it's a sin or not (I will not go with answers that doesn't consider it as a sin by itself), but when I'm being tempted some questions comes up and I fall in sin because the little doubt space if it's a sin, I'd like to know a straightforward answer that proves it's a sin (although I know it's a sin) without rational arguments, by that I mean some stuff like: "you get sad masturbating", "this brings you closer to pornography", "this pollutes your mind", summarizing it all it means "arguments that are based in empiricism, subjectivism, abuse of logic..."

Another argument which I will not go with is "you are commenting adultery in your mind" because it's not from what a masturbation is by own but just a consequence, I know the Bible doesn't state about that very clear... but I'm hopefully in to find out a raw argument, I was studying about that, those bellow are the best arguments that I find out but I'd like to find something stronger:

- In my language, fornication is any sexual act from marriage outside but in English dictionary is to have sex with another one without being married to each other so from Portuguese dictionary masturbation is easily a sin but on English one not.
- Masturbation can be seen as an immoral sexuality but some Bible translate this as fornication and there is no formal definition for sexual immorality.
- The strongest one is Jude 1:7: "7 as Sodom and Gomorrah, and the cities around them in a similar manner to these, having given themselves over to sexual immorality and gone after strange flesh, are set forth as an example, suffering the vengeance of eternal fire.", I'm not sure what "gone after strange flesh" really means but in my Portuguese Bible it means "non natural sexual relationship" since a natural relationship from the bible seems to mean "sex in marriage" is easier to go masturbation as sin but I'm not satisfied with the such argument because the Bible doesn't say "a natural sexual relation is...."

PS: I'm not accepting rational arguments because by rational arguments so many things don't make sense in bible, example why is "OK" pay within an eternity for something you done in your finite life? by logic the bible has some contradictions and so on...

Comment: @DaviAmérico I certainly don't mind us narrowing it down to Pentecostalism, but if you're not satisfied with answers to the other question it can be a little tricky to find a way to phrase another question.  If this question isn't really _about_ masturbation, but about how you can be damned for things you believe are insignificant - that's a much different question.

Comment: In order to ask this question you first need to show that Pentecostals do actually teach that it is a sin. Please [edit] this to add some quotes which say that.

Answer (score 2):

Man was made for woman, and woman for man. Sexuality is meant to be a coming-together of two parts which make a better whole (Genesis 2:18-24). It should be clear that adultery tends to damage this relationship. Moreover, sexual perversions (pornography, homosexuality, bestiality, *masturbation*, etc.) are all ways of seeking sexual pleasure outside of this intended relationship. They are, in effect, a rejection of God's intended plan for humans. Some would also argue they are a rebellion against God's command in Genesis 1:28.

That said, the Bible also commends bachelorhood, which would seem to argue against the idea that not having children is in itself sinful. Even in that case, however, the argument against God's intended way for sexuality to be expressed still applies, as do all Biblical commendations to sobriety. In that respect, masturbation (and pornography) are similar to drunkenness, in that they become pursuits that distance one from God.

> there is no formal definition for sexual immorality

There are at least two definitions which are widely used:

- Any sexual activity outside of heterosexual marriage.
- Any sexual activity which precludes or attempts to avoid conception.

In my experience, the former believed rather widely among Christians and seems to have good Biblical support. The latter is an even stricter definition which is held by some Christians, particularly Roman Catholics.

Masturbation is a pursuit of the pleasures of the flesh outside of the means which God has established. It is an act in which does not glorify God or conform to any expressed intention of God, wherein one is focused on self-pleasure, and often corresponds to a lack of self-control. There are many Biblical teachings admonishing the Christian to exercise discipline over his or her own body. It may also represent a sort of "end run" around a relationship which God desires (that between husband and wife).

Comment: why and where does bachelorhood implie to "which would seem to argue against the idea that not having children is in itself sinful"?

Comment: @DaviAmérico, the Bible (1 Corinthians 7:8) definitely says that it is commendable, for those who are able, to not marry. Since once cannot (without committing adultery) have children without marrying, it therefore follows that not having children cannot be sinful. And, of course, Christ, who was without sin, did not have children.

Comment: matthew I need talk with you 55 85 9986 0937, I think would not be worth to make another posting, these things are better to talk of in a chat.

Comment: @DaviAmérico, https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137812

Answer (score 1):

To your first bullet point, how could masturbation be a sin in one language, but not another, due to a simple technicality of linguistic definition? The act itself either is or is not sinful. It doesn't matter which language you use to talk about it (although linguistic difference may affect how you talk about the issue and clarifications that need to be made).

The simplest answer as to why masturbation is a sin is that God did not design the human body for masturbation. Jesus says that in the beginning, God created them [us] male and female. Sexual acts are not complete divorced from this male/female context. Furthermore, it is evident that God created sex for procreation, and for marriage. To do sexual acts outside of procreation (at least an openness to life) and marriage, therefore, is clearly wrong. Masturbation is a sexual act which takes place outside of both contexts; it is neither within marriage nor is it procreative.

**Edit:** I've got a note here asking for a credible source, as if it isn't just common knowledge that this is the Catholic teaching on sex. Here is a source: https://www.usccb.org/issues-and-action/marriage-and-family/natural-family-planning/catholic-teaching/upload/Openness-to-life.pdf

Comment: Does your answer imply that avoiding children, withing marriage, is a sin? your answer is subjective,  God Doesn't created me to eat chocolate and stuff...

Comment: Having sex without being open to life is a sin, yes. See: https://www.usccb.org/issues-and-action/marriage-and-family/natural-family-planning/catholic-teaching/upload/Openness-to-life.pdf